# Unschedule update method in cocos2d-x

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

I want to unschedule update method after 5 minutes of game start.

I scheduled my update method in constructor of my class.

```
scheduleUpdate();
```

I am trying to unschedule my selector by calling stop update method. But it's not unscheduling.

```
runAction(Sequence::createWithTwoActions(
        DelayTime::create(5.0f),
        CallFuncN::create(this, callfuncN_selector(GameScene::stopupdate))));

Stopupdate method :-

    unscheduleUpdate();
```

Comment: sounds like a scope issue after the delay.

Comment: @GameDeveloper ,  what you think about this issue.?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, DelayTime::create(5.0f) will create delay of 5 secs. Not 5 minutes.

Have you check with some log or etc that code reaches stopUpdate method ?
CallFuncN is used when function accepts CCNode * param.
You should use CallFunc.
And i am guessing, that is this->unsheduleUpdate();

Also, if this all doesn't help, 
use schedule() to custom schedule a function.
You can set this to frame rate and on repeat, so it works same as a scheduleUpdate.
unschedule() to unschedule it.